How to solve the error of Spring content-type = utf8?
"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:213)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:159)\r\n
I tried by giving  @JsonManagedReference and   @JsonBackReference annotations

This error is very small. Just don’t use generalized mapping; instead use @Get, @Post, @Put, etc. I.e., very specific mappings instead of @RequestMappings.
Also, you can try:
@JsonIgnoreProperties ({  
 // inside it include all the reference variables | I repeat dont miss any 
})

The above two steps will solve the issue.

  @JsonIgnoreProperties({"books_in_trans_table", "bookList_S","bookList_A","authored_by" ,"students_in_trans_table", "my_student","transactionList_B","transactionList_S" })
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Author authored_by;

